# FosUserBundle how can logged with ROLE_ADMIN or SUPERADMIN?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i have installed correctly the FOSUserBundle

but my questions are 2
 for logged with a admin?
and i not understand how set some user to admin
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security in Symfony2 is mainly based on user roles, so if the user has admin roles as defined in your security configuration you should have 'admin' user. Maybe you should look into the docs.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles

In case you are using SonataAdminBundle check http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html